# Should I use @Index with Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I have max. 600000 Realm objects in my database. I make queries by id(int)=, uuid=, and time(int)<= and the results is ordered by time. Should I use the @Index annotation for some of the fields and maybe change the id from Integer to String? Are the queries going to be slow because I cannot index the time field and cannot have a multiple field index? Would Sqlite better suit my need?

Also, if I'm storing a large number of objects to the database at once, should I use one transaction for all objects or create a new transaction for each objects? How much memory will a large transaction consume and is there a performance hit when creating a new transaction for each object?

The database will be in external storage (memory card) of the Android device.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely use `@Index` on any field that you use in any query.

It greatly improves performance / query speed.

Comment: Even on boolean? Would it still make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it makes query speed faster

Comment: Can I Index more than one Field?

Comment: You can put Index on 1 field, but you cannot have composite index (1 index for 2 fields) unfortunately.

Comment: So Currently, I have dateTime as Index. Can I make "username" Index too?

Comment: Ah, yes, you can definitely add an `@Index` on both fields. One on `dateTime` and one on `username`.

Comment: Just one quick question. I want to get distinct name in "transactionObject" but I am unable to find the Case.INSENSITIVE with distinct query. Any way to do this?

Comment: Only if you also save a lowercase variant of `transactionObject` like `transactionObjectLowerCase` then distinct by that lowercase field o-o

Comment: I don't have any such variants. How to make that? So, it will be like making a copy of "transactionObject" but with lowercase fields.

Comment: You do it at insertion time of data and yes it will be a copy of that field. The shorter answer  was "no, there is no distinct case_insensitive"

Answer (score 4):

Christian from Realm here. With regard to @Index, then we are soon going to add it for integers as well. If you are concerned about speed, I would probably benchmark the different options to see which approach suits you better, as answering these questions are quite hard in the general case.

With the regard to transactions, it is usually faster to batch as much as possible inside one transaction as there is overhead associated with creating and committing a transaction, but everything inside a transaction has to fit in memory. So depending on how large the dataset is, it might have to be broken up in smaller batches. Again making a small proof-of-concept is is probably the best approach to see what works best in your specific case.

Comment: So, I assume if Realm cannot use indexes, it will make a "full row scan"? Are the indexes real b-tree indexes where you can make also other than equals queries or just hash tables? How is sorting implemented? Is the result set sorted in memory after the query or while making the query?

Comment: Realm is column based, so searching single columns are actually really fast. Our indexes are b+trees and sorting is done in-memory after the query.

Comment: Does this mean that all rows are read to memory and sorted even if I access only the first two objects in the result set?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by read to memory? Realm is a memory-mapped database with a zero-copy architecture. When you do a query we create a lightweight datastructure (called row accessor) that point to the real data, and that is what gets sorted, not the data itself. This is all happening in c++. No data is copied to Java, it is only fetched from c++ when actually read, eg. this is why our collections are so lightweight.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior what if I use field as primary key and index?? and multiple index fields? is it appropriate use of?